# jetpack compose cut composable in half

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

how can I cut composables like `Text` or `Button` like the image below in jetpack compose?

[image]

Comment: it's just letters, thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `drawWithContent` modifier.

```
Button(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier.drawWithContent {
        if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
            clipRect(left = size.width / 2f) {
                this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
            }
        } else {
            clipRect(right = size.width / 2f) {
                this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text("some text")
}
```

Noticing that I added support for RTL languages cutting off the left of the component.

Comment: But it also take space of cut Half